# How to include SimpleImputer before CountVectorizer in a scikit-learn Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imputation, countvectorizer

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that includes a column of text, and I would like to **vectorize the text** using scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer`. However, the text includes missing values, and so I would like to **impute a constant value before vectorizing.**

My initial idea was to create a `Pipeline` of `SimpleImputer` and `CountVectorizer`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['abc def', 'abc ghi', np.nan]})

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer()

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(imp, vect)

pipe.fit_transform(df[['text']]).toarray()
```

However, the `fit_transform` errors because `SimpleImputer` outputs a **2D array** and `CountVectorizer` requires **1D input**. Here's the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

**QUESTION:** How can I modify this `Pipeline` so that it will work?

**NOTE:** I'm aware that I can impute missing values in pandas. However, I would like to accomplish all preprocessing in scikit-learn so that the same preprocessing can be applied to new data using `Pipeline`.

Comment: Why not impute the missing values in the original dataframe: `df.fillna("")`?

Comment: @DYZ As I mentioned at the bottom of my question, I'd like to accomplish all of the preprocessing in scikit-learn so that I can use Pipeline to apply the same preprocessing to new data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to **insert a custom transformer** into the `Pipeline` that reshapes the output of `SimpleImputer` from 2D to 1D before it is passed to `CountVectorizer`.

Here's the complete code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['abc def', 'abc ghi', np.nan]})

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer()

# CREATE TRANSFORMER
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
one_dim = FunctionTransformer(np.reshape, kw_args={'newshape':-1})

# INCLUDE TRANSFORMER IN PIPELINE
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(imp, one_dim, vect)

pipe.fit_transform(df[['text']]).toarray()
```

It has been [proposed on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16972) that `CountVectorizer` should allow 2D input as long as the second dimension is 1 (meaning: a single column of data). That modification to `CountVectorizer` would be a great solution to this problem!

Answer (score 7):

One solution would be to create a class off SimpleImputer and override its `transform()` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer


class ModifiedSimpleImputer(SimpleImputer):
    def transform(self, X):
        return super().transform(X).flatten()


df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['abc def', 'abc ghi', np.nan]})

imp = ModifiedSimpleImputer(strategy='constant')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer()

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(imp, vect)

pipe.fit_transform(df[['text']]).toarray()
```

Comment: Or vice versa:

`class ModifiedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):   
    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        return super().fit_transform(X.flatten())`

Answer (score 0):

I use this one dimensional wrapper for sklearn Transformer when I have one dimensional data. I think, this wrapper can be used to wrap the simpleImputer for the one dimensional data (a pandas series with string values) in your case.

```
class OneDWrapper:
    """One dimensional wrapper for sklearn Transformers"""

    def __init__(self, transformer):
        self.transformer = transformer

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.transformer.fit(np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1))
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.transformer.transform(
            np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()

    def inverse_transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.transformer.inverse_transform(
            np.expand_dims(X, axis=1)).ravel()
```

Now, you don't need an additional step in the pipeline.

```
one_d_imputer = OneDWrapper(SimpleImputer(strategy='constant'))
pipe = make_pipeline(one_d_imputer, vect)
pipe.fit_transform(df['text']).toarray() 
# note we are feeding a pd.Series here!
```